# Gson парсер Java. Как распарсить файл?

Tags: java, json, gson

Доброе утро. Имеется JSON файл формата

```js
{
    "WA": [
        [
            [
                [-117.033359, 49.000239],
                [-117.044313, 47.762451],
                [-117.038836, 46.426077],
                [-117.055267, 46.343923],
                [-116.92382, 46.168661],
                [-116.918344, 45.993399],
                [-118.988627, 45.998876],
                [-119.125551, 45.933153],
                [-119.525367, 45.911245],
                [-119.963522, 45.823614],
                [-120.209985, 45.725029],
                [-120.505739, 45.697644],
                [-120.637186, 45.746937],
                [-121.18488, 45.604536],
                [-121.217742, 45.670259],
                [-121.535404, 45.725029],
                [-121.809251, 45.708598],
                [-122.247407, 45.549767],
                [-122.762239, 45.659305],
                [-122.811531, 45.960537],
                [-122.904639, 46.08103],
                [-123.11824, 46.185092],
                [-123.211348, 46.174138],
                [-123.370179, 46.146753],
                [-123.545441, 46.261769],
                [-123.72618, 46.300108],
                [-123.874058, 46.239861],
                [-124.065751, 46.327492],
                [-124.027412, 46.464416],
                [-123.895966, 46.535616],
                [-124.098612, 46.74374],
                [-124.235536, 47.285957],
                [-124.31769, 47.357157],
                [-124.427229, 47.740543],
                [-124.624399, 47.88842],
                [-124.706553, 48.184175],
                [-124.597014, 48.381345],
                [-124.394367, 48.288237],
                [-123.983597, 48.162267],
                [-123.704273, 48.167744],
                [-123.424949, 48.118452],
                [-123.162056, 48.167744],
                [-123.036086, 48.080113],
                [-122.800578, 48.08559],
                [-122.636269, 47.866512],
                [-122.515777, 47.882943],
                [-122.493869, 47.587189],
                [-122.422669, 47.318818],
                [-122.324084, 47.346203],
                [-122.422669, 47.576235],
                [-122.395284, 47.800789],
                [-122.230976, 48.030821],
                [-122.362422, 48.123929],
                [-122.373376, 48.288237],
                [-122.471961, 48.468976],
                [-122.422669, 48.600422],
                [-122.488392, 48.753777],
                [-122.647223, 48.775685],
                [-122.795101, 48.8907],
                [-122.756762, 49.000239],
                [-117.033359, 49.000239]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [-122.718423, 48.310145],
                [-122.586977, 48.35396],
                [-122.608885, 48.151313],
                [-122.767716, 48.227991],
                [-122.718423, 48.310145]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [-123.025132, 48.583992],
                [-122.915593, 48.715438],
                [-122.767716, 48.556607],
                [-122.811531, 48.419683],
                [-123.041563, 48.458022],
                [-123.025132, 48.583992]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

[image: pic]
<sub>(источник: [userapi.com](https://pp.userapi.com/c636825/v636825574/6052e/q_n2Lfyl2Go.jpg))</sub>

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StatesData.doWithSimpleMappings(new FileReader("F:\\BigProject\\data\\states.json"));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public class StatesData {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static final Type payloadType = new TypeToken<Map<String, double[][][][]>>() {
    }.getType();

    static void doWithSimpleMappings(final FileReader reader) {
        gson.<Map<String, double[][][][]>>fromJson(reader, payloadType)
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> {
                    System.out.println("State: " + e.getKey());
                    return Stream.of(e.getValue());
                })
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .flatMap(doubles -> {
                    System.out.println("\tPolygon:");
                    return Stream.of(doubles);
                })
                .forEach(doubles -> System.out.println("\t\t(" + doubles[0] + ";" + doubles[1] + ")"));
    }
    }
```

Второй день бьюсь над этим экзепшном. Куда копать?(

**Exception:** com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 1891 path $.[0][0][0]

Comment: 1. На вашей картинке не видно ничего, от слова совсем 2. Для парсинга json есть более простые способы, смотрите в сторону `JSONObject`

Comment: Поправил картинку.

Comment: вместо картинки опубликуйте фрагмент кода

Comment: Картинка - содержимое json файла...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самом вопросе предлагается жирное и слабоструктурированное решение, которое не совсем оптимально расходует память. Есть другие решения, которые включают и маппинг JSON-документа в простейшие структуры данных, и более сложные маппинги (кстати, почему бы не десериализировать прямо в `Polygon`? (AWT? JavaFX? что-то своё?)), а также читать входной поток JSON-документа.

Допустим, есть следующий JSON-документ (который, я надеюсь, отображает *то*, что вы прикрепили к вопросу -- **глаза и зрение дороже** + было бы просто удобнее):

*(пример JSON-а удалено из-за редактирования вопроса)*

Элементарнейшим решением здесь является такой подход:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
private static final Type payloadType = new TypeToken<Map<String, double[][][][]>>() {
}.getType();

static void doWithSimpleMappings(final Reader reader) {
    gson.<Map<String, double[][][][]>>fromJson(reader, payloadType)
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> {
                System.out.println("State: " + e.getKey());
                return Stream.of(e.getValue());
            })
            .flatMap(Stream::of)
            .flatMap(doubles -> {
                System.out.println("\tPolygon:");
                return Stream.of(doubles);
            })
            .forEach(doubles -> System.out.println("\t\t(" + doubles[0] + ";" + doubles[1] + ")"));
}
```

Обратите внимание, что числа с двойной точностью описаны как примитивы и, таким образом, экономят память, не оборачивая значения в `java.lang.Double`.

Другим подходом, немного более совершенным, может быть отказ от `double[]` в качестве объекта, в который можно записать координату. Расход памяти, по крайней мере готового результата (а не собственно разбора, скрытого в недрах Gson), будет приблизительно равен расходу в первом случае. Но у `latitude` и `latitude` куда более осмысленное значение (+ не уверен вообще, но доступ к элементам массива немного дороже из-за отсуствия проверок на выход за границы массива, но это явно зависит уже от того как устроена JVM -- я так глубоко никогда не копался; да и это вообще микрооптимизация, семантика здесь удобнее).

```java
final class Point {

    final double latitude;
    final double longitude;

    Point(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + latitude + ";" + longitude + ")";
    }

}
```

Теперь нужно рассказать Gson, как обращаться с Point, иначе он буде ожидать JSON-объекты вида `{"latitude": ..., "longitude": ...}`. Для этого предназначены `TypeAdapter`-ы, которые хоть и более сложны в написании, но выгоднее в плане экономии ресурсов чем `JsonSerializer` и `JsonDeserializer`, которые оперируют JSON-представлениями прямо в памяти.

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Point.class, new TypeAdapter<Point>() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Point point)
                    throws IOException {
                out.beginArray();
                out.value(point.latitude);
                out.value(point.longitude);
                out.endArray();
            }

            @Override
            public Point read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                in.beginArray();
                final double latitude = in.nextDouble();
                final double longitude = in.nextDouble();
                in.endArray();
                return new Point(latitude, longitude);
            }
        }.nullSafe())
        .create();

private static final Type payloadType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<List<List<Point>>>>>() {
}.getType();

static void doWithComplexMappings(final Reader reader) {
    gson.<Map<String, List<List<List<Point>>>>>fromJson(reader, payloadType)
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> {
                System.out.println("State: " + e.getKey());
                return Stream.of(e.getValue());
            })
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .flatMap(lists -> {
                System.out.println("\tPolygon:");
                return lists.stream();
            })
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .forEach(point -> System.out.println("\t\t" + point));
}
```

Ну и самым сложным вариантом, который может куда эффективнее работать с большими объемами данных является отказ от маппинга вообще и разбор JSON-токенов вручную. Поскольку `JsonReader` не обладает никакими семантическими (по крайней мере, с точки зрения приложения) ожиданиями, придётся написать парсер, который будет промежуточным звеном между парсингом JSON-документа и приложением (причём, обработчики вообще не зависят от JSON как такового и могут спокойно работать и с XML и с любыми другими источниками данных вообще).

```java
interface IListener {

    void acceptState(String state);

    void acceptL1Begin();

    void acceptL1End();

    void acceptL2Begin();

    void acceptL2End();

    void acceptPolygonBegin();

    void acceptPolygonEnd();

    void acceptCoordinate(double latitude, double longitude);

}

static void doWithStreaming(final Reader reader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader) ) {
        parseL0Key(jsonReader, listener);
    }
}

private static void parseL0Key(final JsonReader jsonReader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        listener.acceptState(jsonReader.nextName());
        parseL1(jsonReader, listener);
    }
    jsonReader.endObject();
}

private static void parseL1(final JsonReader jsonReader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    listener.acceptL1Begin();
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        parseL2(jsonReader, listener);
    }
    listener.acceptL1End();
    jsonReader.endArray();
}

private static void parseL2(final JsonReader jsonReader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    listener.acceptL2Begin();
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        parseL3Polygons(jsonReader, listener);
    }
    listener.acceptL2End();
    jsonReader.endArray();
}

private static void parseL3Polygons(final JsonReader jsonReader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    listener.acceptPolygonBegin();
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        parseL4Coordinate(jsonReader, listener);
    }
    listener.acceptPolygonEnd();
    jsonReader.endArray();
}

private static void parseL4Coordinate(final JsonReader jsonReader, final IListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    listener.acceptCoordinate(jsonReader.nextDouble(), jsonReader.nextDouble());
    jsonReader.endArray();
}
```

Пример использования такого подхода:

```java
doWithStreaming(reader, new Streaming.IListener() {
    private final List<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    private int level;

    @Override
    public void acceptState(final String key) {
        print("State: " + key);
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptL1Begin() {
        level++;
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptL1End() {
        level--;
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptL2Begin() {
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptL2End() {
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptPolygonBegin() {
        print("Polygon:");
        level++;
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptPolygonEnd() {
        coordinates.forEach(this::print);
        coordinates.clear();
        level--;
    }

    @Override
    public void acceptCoordinate(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        coordinates.add(new Point(latitude, longitude));
    }

    private void print(final Object message) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }
});
```

Результатом для всех без решений выше будет одинаковый вывод следующего дерева:

> State: WA
>     Polygon:
>         (-117.033359;49.000239)
>         (-117.044313;47.762451)
>         (-117.038836;46.426077)
>         (-117.055267;46.343923)
>         (-116.92382;46.168661)
>         (-116.918344;45.993399)
>         (-118.988627;45.998876)
>         (-119.125551;45.933153)
>         (-119.525367;45.911245)
>         (-119.963522;45.823614)
>         (-120.209985;45.725029)
>         (-120.505739;45.697644)
>         (-120.637186;45.746937)
>         (-121.18488;45.604536)
>         (-121.217742;45.670259)
>         (-121.535404;45.725029)
>         (-121.809251;45.708598)
>         (-122.247407;45.549767)
>         (-122.762239;45.659305)
>         (-122.811531;45.960537)
>         (-122.904639;46.08103)
>         (-123.11824;46.185092)
>         (-123.211348;46.174138)
>         (-123.370179;46.146753)
>         (-123.545441;46.261769)
>         (-123.72618;46.300108)
>         (-123.874058;46.239861)
>         (-124.065751;46.327492)
>         (-124.027412;46.464416)
>         (-123.895966;46.535616)
>         (-124.098612;46.74374)
>         (-124.235536;47.285957)
>         (-124.31769;47.357157)
>         (-124.427229;47.740543)
>         (-124.624399;47.88842)
>         (-124.706553;48.184175)
>         (-124.597014;48.381345)
>         (-124.394367;48.288237)
>         (-123.983597;48.162267)
>         (-123.704273;48.167744)
>         (-123.424949;48.118452)
>         (-123.162056;48.167744)
>         (-123.036086;48.080113)
>         (-122.800578;48.08559)
>         (-122.636269;47.866512)
>         (-122.515777;47.882943)
>         (-122.493869;47.587189)
>         (-122.422669;47.318818)
>         (-122.324084;47.346203)
>         (-122.422669;47.576235)
>         (-122.395284;47.800789)
>         (-122.230976;48.030821)
>         (-122.362422;48.123929)
>         (-122.373376;48.288237)
>         (-122.471961;48.468976)
>         (-122.422669;48.600422)
>         (-122.488392;48.753777)
>         (-122.647223;48.775685)
>         (-122.795101;48.8907)
>         (-122.756762;49.000239)
>         (-117.033359;49.000239)
>     Polygon:
>         (-122.718423;48.310145)
>         (-122.586977;48.35396)
>         (-122.608885;48.151313)
>         (-122.767716;48.227991)
>         (-122.718423;48.310145)
>     Polygon:
>         (-123.025132;48.583992)
>         (-122.915593;48.715438)
>         (-122.767716;48.556607)
>         (-122.811531;48.419683)
>         (-123.041563;48.458022)
>         (-123.025132;48.583992)